# Bootstrap from search box needs to be wider that bootstrap allows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a bootstrap form text box to be wider than what bootstrap allows by default.

The URL of the page with the search box is: www.allthings.trade/farming

If someone could look at the source of the textbox and tell me what I am doing wrong.

I have tried this sample on my page and it doesn't work.

Comment: Add some code, please, to let us help you...

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot of website]

Is the red area the needed space for the text box?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your CSS code:

```
input#SearchString {
  max-width: 98%;
}
```

And change `col-md-3 col-md-offset-3` to `col-md-6` for the search box.